# Override SSL Certificate OR Ciphers for AWS lambda (function URL or API Gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway

Have a JDK7 app invoking an AWS lambda, currently configured via a lambda function URL. Looks like we have an incompatible cpiher set, is it possible to override the SSL Certificate or the ciphers used with a function URL?

If not, is this possible using API Gateway?